# Adding input tools to a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, django

Am creating a blog website in Django where bloggers are not familiar with Markdown/Markup. So am planning to add these tools to my textarea.(image below).
[image]

Please suggest an easy way to achieve this.

Comment: Use a Rich Text Editor https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/

Comment: You can also use `django-ckeditor`.

Answer (score 2):

Use WYSIWYG Editor like summernote

https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote